# Why is my nginx rate limiting not working?

Tags: nginx

I have Nginx in front of apache to terminate SSL and filter things. I'm trying to get rate limiting working using [these docs](https://www.nginx.com/blog/mitigating-ddos-attacks-with-nginx-and-nginx-plus).

When I test a loop of 10 requests with *curl*, all the requests for */mytest/* are still being forwarded back to Apache - 8 of them show the same timestamp down to the second. I'm expecting only one request/second should reach Apache. What have I overlooked?

My *curl* command:

```
for i in $(seq 1 10); do curl --verbose  --request "GET /mytest" https://myhost.com; done
```

*nginx.conf*:

```
http {
   ...
   include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
   ...
}
```

*/etc/nginx/conf.d/rate-limit.conf*:

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/s;

server {
   location /mytest/ {
      limit_req zone=one;    #:: removed burst=5 for testing - made no diff
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your location with rate limit is `/mytest/` but you are requesting `/mytest` (without a trailing slash). These requests won't match that location.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm not sure what I did, but it is working now. Strangely enough, it seems to be working with or without the trailing slash so not sure why that is.

Comment: i have the exact same problem, after hours and hours i'm unable to solve, my code is like yours i can't understand.